# Is this Coldfusion query SQL Injection proof?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Typically I use integer ids in my application, but for this one piece of dev I am doing look ups on a text field - a tag name.

I do make use of cfqueryparam but considering that it's a text field, could it be vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and if so, how do other people get around this other than tediously searching the string for SQL commands.

My query looks something like:

```
SELECT tagId -- etc etc
FROM tag
WHERE tagName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#arguments.tagName#" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually, most of the time, with ColdFusion and PHP strings are harder to inject against than integers because both systems use something call "magic quotes". But magic quotes do not make it impossible to inject, so you should use cfqueryparam anyway as others have already said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's safe by virtue of the fact that you're using `<cfqueryparam>`.  That's what the tag does.  It sends the value as text (or whatever the cfsqltype happens to be), *not* a command to be executed.

Comment: Ok great - thanks - this is what I was looking for. The fact that cfqueryparam prevents any commands from being executed. Just wasn't sure if that was the case for varchar params. Good to know it is.

Answer (score 7):

For the most part yes... doing sql injection for this would be very difficult. CFQUERYPARAM does make it almost impossible to sql inject a query.  However, remember that nothing is 100% effective against all forms of attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not use cfqueryparam, then you would be vulnerable.

By using cfqueryparam you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Try putting in injection attacks and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard somewhere that using `cfqueryparam` together with [Portcullis](http://portcullis.riaforge.org/) would be a stronger protection against XSS and block malicious hack attempts.

> Most ColdFusion web developers are now finally using cfqueryparam, it
>   has taken about 10 years since that tag was introduced but I guess
>   better late than never. Keep in mind, that cfqueryparam prevents most
>   forms of SQL injection but not all. It also does nothing to cross-site
>   scripting (XSS) attacks. It doesn't matter how small your site is or
>   where it's hosted, it will experience these attack vectors. Portcullis
>   takes maybe 5 minutes to install and configure. Nothing is perfect,
>   but Portcullis has a solid track record - just google it. So, there's
>   simply no reason I can think of where a ColdFusion based site
>   shouldn't use it.

http://www.codfusion.com/blog/post.cfm/portcullis-2-0-released

Also, you may want to watch [CFMeetup: Warning, your site is under attack](http://experts.na3.acrobat.com/p23722381/) presented by John Mason, the author of Portcullis.

Comment: just watched.  Portcullis does scope scans with blacklisted keywords, and also ban malicious users

Comment: Black listing is never a stronger defense than proper query paraming. If you heard somewhere that Portcullis is stronger protection than good coding practices, you heard wrong or they gave you incorrect information.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer.  I should have said it is stronger when using `cfqueryparam` together with Portcullis...