# (ColdFusion + Access) Database Query Error "Too few parameters."

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion

I'm about to rip my hair out with this one.

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3.

The error occurred in [WITHHELD]: line 19

17 :                 WHERE      FNAME = #FORM.first#
18 :                 AND            LNAME = #FORM.last#
19 :                 AND            PASS = #FORM.pass#
20 :             </cfquery>
21 :         

SQLSTATE      07002
SQL        SELECT * FROM JUDGES WHERE FNAME = [WITHHELD] AND LNAME = [WITHHELD] AND PASS = [WITHHELD]
VENDORERRORCODE       -3010
DATASOURCE    honors
```

I've read a number of similar issues where there was some spelling error but I've checked and rechecked spellings, even changed column and table names and tried again.

Comment: do you have quotes around the variables in your real code? ie `fname = '#form.first#'`

Comment: @Antony: No. Though I have tried it with quotes around FNAME, LNAME, and PASS just to see. It still didn't work.

Comment: do you get the error for all values of `WITHHELD` - any quotes or funny characters in the form values?

Comment: @Antony: Looking at your post again, I saw you just used single quotes. Tried that and it worked. Had been using double. Thanks!

Comment: great - i'll write it up as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that you quote your variables:

`where FNAME = '#FORM.first#'`

Additionally, you should really use `cfqueryparam` to protect against [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030676/is-this-coldfusion-query-sql-injection-proof/7030773#7030773):

`where FNAME = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.first#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">`

(Note that you do not need the quotes when using `cfqueryparam`)

- `cfqueryparam` [documentation](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam)
- a note about [MS Access support](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2007/12/cfqueryparam-matrix-for-ms-access.html) for `cfqueryparam`